# How to convert a text file into dictionary?

Tags: python

From a file, I am supposed to return a dictionary where each key is a person's name, and each value is a list with three elements in this order: the person's gender, the person's age and the person's height.

For example, if my file "file.txt" has two lines like this:

Peter, male, 18, 180
Andrew, male, 40, 175

Then the dictionary returned by this function would be:

{"Peter": ["male", 18, 180], "Andrew": ["male", 40, 175]}

I tried:

```
d={}
L=[]
f= open("items.txt","r")
for line in f:
    (key, val) = line.split(",",1)
    value= val.split(",")
    L.append(value)
    d[key] = L
return d
f.close()
```

And it returns:
{'Peter': [[' male', ' 18', ' 180 \n'], [' male', ' 40', ' 175']], 'Andrew': [[' male', ' 18', ' 180 \n'], [' male', ' 40', ' 175']]}

Comment: What is the criterion of separation?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: put what you have tried in the question itself. and tell us whats not working.

Comment: in the question please, not in comments. [edit] your post

Comment: What ***should*** the dictionary look like that gets produced? What is wrong with what you getting from your code? Note that the `line.split(",",1)`looks like it's wrong—it only allows one split per line to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the same `L` variable, resulting in an accumulation effect you don't want. Besides, it doesn't convert integers strings to integers, and doesn't remove end of line chars for the last item.

Other small mistake is returning the value and closing the file afterwards (this close statement isn't reached, so the file is closed whenever python decides. A `with` context manager is always better in those cases)

if `f` is your file handle (or a list of lines), this one-liner does the job:

```
f="""a,b,1,2
apple,banana,3,4""".splitlines()

d = {t[0]:[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x.rstrip() for x in t[1:]] for t in (l.split(",") for l in f)}
```

it splits according to comma, then builds a dict comprehension, using first item as key and other items as values, using `rstrip` to handle the newline of the last field.

The extra string to integer conversion uses `isdigit` so it's not perfect. (doesn't work for negative numbers). Can be replaced by an aux function.

result:

```
{'apple': ['banana', 3, 4], 'a': ['b', 1, 2]}
```